# I cannot reference a Gradle custom extension using a closure

Tags: gradle, plugins

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin that uses an extension. Here's what the relevant part look like:

```
class Aar2Jar implements org.gradle.api.Plugin<Project> {

void apply (Project project) {
    println('applying Android Jar')
    def ext = project.extensions.create('jarSpec', JarSpecExtension)
    if (ext.name.get() == "") {
        ext.name.set(project.name)
    }
```

and Here's what the extension looks like:

```
package test.android.gradle

import org.gradle.api.provider.Property

abstract class JarSpecExtension {
    abstract Property<String> getName()
    abstract Property<String> getVersion()
    abstract Property<String> getInclude()
    abstract Property<String> getExclude()

    JarSpecExtension() {
        name.convention("")
        version.convention("1.0.0")
        include.convention("*")
        exclude.convention("")
    }
}
```

And here's what my build.gradle script that uses this custom plugin looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'test.android.jar'
}

jarSpec {
    name = 'myJar'
}
```

The problem is that doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'test.android.jar']
> Failed to apply plugin 'test.android.jar'.
   > No such property: extensions for class: test.android.gradle.Aar2Jar
```

However, if I change the build.gradle file to this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'test.android.jar'
}

jarSpec.name = 'myJar'
```

It works perfect. The question is why can I not refer to the extension using the closure style.  I'm using gradle version 7.2.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but I tried it again not having made any changes and it's now working for both styles.  Might have been some caching error because the built plugin is stored in mavenLocal and the project that uses the plugin retrieves it from mavenLocal.